# Count occurrences of each combination

Tags: sql, excel, combinations, permutation

I have 5 conditions (A-E) and a bunch of patient ID's. My data set is 2 columns: PatientID, Condition.

There are duplicate PatientID's with every new condition:

| PatientID | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | C |
| 456 | E |
| 279 | D |
| 123 | A |
| 123 | C |
| 123 | D |
| 187 | D |
| 296 | E |
| 296 | C |

I believe there are 31 different potential combinations (order doesn't matter) of those 5 conditions (ie A, AB, ABC, AC, ACDE, etc)

I want to count how many patients in each combination of conditions. So my results for the above would be -
CE: 2
D: 2
ACD: 1

I'm more familiar with Excel but if this is better handled in SQL, I can do it there. I think I need to create a table of all the different combinations (any help on that would be appreciated too) and then do a count from there but I'm not sure if that's the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server solution

```
SELECT
    conditions,
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        patientid,
        STRING_AGG(condition, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY condition) conditions
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY patientid
) c
GROUP BY conditions
```

Output

| conditions | patient_count |
| --- | --- |
| ACD | 1 |
| CE | 2 |
| D | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98e0b580ab26c933c5f76370d2a9b33b)*

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PatientID", Int64.Type}, {"Condition", type text}}),

//Group by ID and aggregate a sorted list of each ID's conditions
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PatientID"}, {
        {"Conditions", each Text.Combine(List.Sort([Condition])), type text}
        }),

//Group by Conditions and aggregate with Count
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"Conditions"}, {{"Condition Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows1"
```

[image]